# Example of a measure space with constraints on values of measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I need to find a measure space $(X,S,\mu)$ such that
$$
\{\mu(E)|E\in S\} = [0,1]\cup[3,\infty] .
$$
*My idea:* I know the result for $[0,1]\cup[3,4]$ in the right hand side because in that case if we consider any probability measure $P$ on $(-\infty, 0)$ and we add $P$ with point measure $3\delta_2$, then it will give the measure with range $[0,1]\cup[3,4]$  but I have
**no idea what to do if the range is** $[0,1]\cup[3,c]$ where $c>4$.

If we get above then in limiting sense we can get a measure  with range $[0,1]\cup[3,\infty]$.

Am I  right? Please give me some hint.

Comment: Can you share what you have for $[0, 1] \cup [3, 4]$? Generally [we look for](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) context or some amount of work shown in questions.

Comment: If we consider probability measure P on (-$\infty$, 0) and we take our measure as P+3$\delta_1$ then its range will be [0,1]$\bigcup$ [3,4].

Comment: SuSe, we encourage you to edit your question to include your added information.  That would be great, and it might be enough to reopen the question.

Comment: Reopened : time for someone to answer it now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The range can't actually be $[0, 1] \cup [3, c]$ for any $c > 4$ unless $c = \infty$. Suppose there were such a measure $\mu$. Let $E$ be such that $3 > c - \mu(E) > 1$. Then $\mu(X \backslash E) = c - \mu(E)$, which lies outside of our range.

In the case $c = \infty$, there's a lot of things we can do. One idea is to "stick a bunch of weighted $\delta$ measures everywhere", which generalizes the example you gave for $c = 4$. Let $\nu$ be the measure such that $\nu(\{x\}) = x$ for $x \in [3, \infty)$ and $0$ on any set disjoint from $[3, \infty)$. Then we can add a probability measure $P$ on $(-\infty, 0)$ as in your example to get a measure $P + \nu$ with range $[0, 1] \cup [3, \infty]$.